# How do I determine the checked state of checkboxes from an array returned by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I determine the state of a checkbox (i.e. checked or unchecked) with the following code:

```
function deleteItems() {
    var items = $('.td_checkbox');
    for (var item in items) {

        // this doesn't work
        if ($(item).is(:checked) == true)
            alert('delete my div if checked!');            
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the html associated with this? Your css class seems to tell me that you're getting a collection of td elements...

Comment: The checkboxes are in a table. The checkbox class="td_checkbox".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need quotes around :checked, but I also don't think your loop works correctly.

This will do what you want (use each() rather than for item in items)

```
function deleteItems() {
    $('.td_checkbox').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            alert('delete my div if checked!');            
    });
}
```

Comment: @Roland: generally you'd want to use `this.checked` rather than `$(this).is(":checked")`, which is needlessly invoking the costly selector engine to do something that is readily available as a property on the `this` object.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the quotes `"` around `:checked`: `.is(":checked")`.

*But doing it the jQuery way:*

```
function deleteItems() {
    $('.td_checkbox:checked').remove(); // or .parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: This is going to be useful too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `attr` property to check and/or set an attribute

```
function deleteItems() {
    var items = $('.td_checkbox');
    for (var item in items) {

        // this doesn't work
        if ($(item).attr('checked') == true)
            $(item).remove();            
    }
}
```

Or you can also filter the checked ones before hand

```
function deleteItems() {
    var items = $('.td_checkbox:checked');
    for (var item in items) {
        $(item).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip jQuery for the checkedness check and just use the checkbox element's couldn't-be-simpler-works-in-every-browser-released-since-1995 `checked` property:

```
function deleteItems() {
    $('.td_checkbox').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert('delete my div if checked!');            
        }
    });
}
```